# Exchange 2010 outgoing public IP address

Tags: exchange, ip

I am planning to publish my exchange server

what i want is to use a:

1- dedicated ip for sending mails 
2- dedicated ip for receiving mails (different than the send IP )

these two ip addresses should be different than my router public ip

i know that i should create NAT on my firewall for the receive , but I need to know how to force my mail server to use a specific public ip for the sent items.

Comment: `1- dedicated ip for sending mails 2- dedicated ip for receiving mails (different than the send IP )` Why do you want this? What advantage do you think this is going to create for you?

Comment: My Main Need is to use a different IP for sending mails rather than My router public ip

I don't wana my mail server to send emails through the same public IP that we use for Internet services

Comment: @AnanZitawi What type of firewall are you using?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Why do you want to send on one address and receive on the other?

Comment: `My router public ip I don't wana my mail server to send emails through the same public IP that we use for Internet services`  Well, then, you're doing something wrong.  Possibly/probably multiple somethings.  Can it be done?  Yes, probably, with some work on your network gear (and the Exchange send/receive connectors), assuming you have multiple IP addresses from your ISP.  Should it be done?  No.  For mostly all the same reasons you shouldn't smoke around a natural gas leak.

Comment: Hmm.  It occurs to me that maybe I should point out the obvious here.  You shouldn't smoke around a natural gas leak because it's pointless, senseless and will do nothing but blow up in your face.

Comment: Dears

i AM USING ZYXEL USG-100 FIREWALL.

MDMARRA , I need this to separate traffic between my public ips

so internet users can surf the web through xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip
mail server send emails through yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy ip 
and receive incoming mails through zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz 

any one think this senario is wrong ????

Comment: @AnanZitawi  Yes, everyone thinks this scenario is wrong.  Why do you want to separate the send and receive email addresses?  What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you have to run **Set-SendConnector SourceIPAddress** x.x.x.x from the EMS in order to set the source ip address (of the Exchange server) for outbound email.

Then create a firewall/NAT rule to NAT outbound traffic from that ip address to your preferred public ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a router/firewall with a feature called Policy Based Routing.

With this you could make a rule like: When traffic is coming from my mail server AND the destination port is 25, send the traffic through this ISP.

Comment: This...(despite the arguments for or against the OP's idea...)  But if the OP is stating `"My Main Need is to use a different IP for sending mails rather than My router public ip I don't wana my mail server to send emails through the same public IP that we use for Internet services"` then that's just a matter of a 2nd public IP and a static NAT for the mail server, while normal web browsing takes place on the original IP.